# Add Remove RegEx Options in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to take regex options as input from user and I am using check boxes to take input, which looks something like following:

```
[ ]IngoreCase  
[ ]Multiline  
[ ]Sigleline  
[ ]RightToLeft
```

etc.

My questions is that how I can pass parameters (RegexOptions) according to option(s) selected by user.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use those options, you "OR" them together into a single value. There is no need to do that in 1 statement within the regex call, you could use something like:

```
var options = RegexOptions.None;
if (checkBoxIgnoreCase.Checked) options = options | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
if (checkBoxMultiLine.Checked) options = options | RegexOptions.MultiLine;
// etc.
```

and use that `options` value in your `Regex.Match`.

Answer (score 3):

use [Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx)

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(RegexOptions));
```

and from string back to enum

```
var option = (RegexOptions)Enum.Parse(typeof(RegexOptions), "IgnoreCase");
```

Comment: I need to set multiple options according to selected.